# How to make google form be Repeatable on section to add more answers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I spent much time to search solution, but could not find any results even add-on, or script examples.
[How to make google form be Repeatable on section to add more answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBNre.jpg)

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can't. Google forms are not shopping carts. They are static. If you need the respondent to repeat a section, they need to fill out the form again. Alternately, design your form with a large number of those sections, each on a different page, and go to a specific page based on the answer, such that each section links to the next - i.e. you drop the person into the chain so they only have as many pages as guests

Comment: (That this is not possible with Google Forms is immediately evident in a Google Search)

Comment: Thanks for reply and how about add-on or scripts?

Comment: @tehhowch. The google search leads to this answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it so that the people who are using your form can submit more than one response and/or edit a response.
This is the closest you can get to the desired result using Google Forms.

[image]

Comment: No, you can create extra sections in advance, and send the respondent to the correct part number based on their answer to "how many guests". But Google Forms does not support dynamic length, and that is what is desired. (Consider how one represents the response in a spreadsheet when the number of items in a section is not known.)

Comment: Aah okay, I did not really understand the question all to well I guess. Yeah "Go to  section based on answer" is totally possible. OP said to add more more answers, sounded like recieve more responses to me.

Comment: Thanks for reply, image sample for question express. Actually maybe  answers over Dozens of times on the same section. Could not submit Dozens of times. any add-on or scripts?

Comment: Hi, your last comment did not make much sense. Could you maybe rephrase your question? @user3504593

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished what I needed using the conditional questions.  When they get to the end of the section I built, I have a question asking if they have another response.  If they say No it goes to submit.  If they say Yes it takes them back to a copy of that section.  I just duplicated the section about a dozen times (you could do more if you anticipate more but that's all I needed) and if they answer yes then they could repeat that section up to the 12 times. It only showed as one response on the results, but when I go to the Sheets it has them all listed out separately just like I wanted.

Comment: Are the entries actually on different rows? When I tried that, it just repeated the column names and put all the answers in one row.